# Scala generic type method matching

Tags: scala, generics

I am building a Scala generic type method that takes tuple with different size and output a line of CSV string. The code I wrote is like this

```
object CSVFormat {
  protected def valueToCSV[T](value: Seq[T]): String =
    s""""${value.map(_.toString).mkString("{", ",", "}")}""""
  protected def valueToCSV[T](value: T): String =
    s""""${value.toString}""""

  def rowToCSV[A](row: (A)): String = valueToCSV(row)
  def rowToCSV[A, B](row: (A, B)): String =
    s"${rowToCSV((row._1))},${rowToCSV((row._2))}"
  def rowToCSV[A, B, C](row: (A, B, C)): String =
    s"${rowToCSV((row._1, row._2))},${rowToCSV((row._3))}"
  def rowToCSV[A, B, C, D](row: (A, B, C, D)): String =
    s"${rowToCSV((row._1, row._2, row._3))},${rowToCSV((row._4))}"
  def rowToCSV[A, B, C, D, E](row: (A, B, C, D, E)): String =
    s"${rowToCSV((row._1, row._2, row._3, row._4))},${rowToCSV((row._5))}"
}
```

What I am trying to get is something like

```
CSVFormat.rowToCSV(("hello", 1234, Seq("a", "b", "c")))
```

then the output should be

```
"hello","1234","{a,b,c}"
```

The major issue here is for `Seq[T]` type matching and just `T` type matching for `valueToCSV` method, it seems just T type always win, so

```
CSVFormat.rowToCSV((Seq("A")))
```

always results in

```
""[(List(A))]""
```

Any idea how to make Scala generic type matching, the `Seq[T]` has higher priority so that it got match first? Or should I determine type in runtime instead of compiling type instead? If so, how should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flavor of `valueToCSV` method is resolved at compile time, when it is not known whether the type you pass in is going to be a sequence or not.

You need a dynamic type check instead. How about something like this:

```
 def rowToCSV[T <: Product](tuple: T) = tuple
  .productIterator
  .map { 
      case s: Seq[_] => s.mkString("{", ",", "}")
      case x => x.toString
   }.mkString("\"", "\",\"", "\"")
```

BTW, you don't need the parenthesis when calling a function, whose only argument is a tuple: `rowToCSV("foo")` is the same as `rowToCSV(("foo"))` and `rowToCSV(1, "foo", Seq("bar", "baz"))` is the same as `rowToCSV((1, "foo", Seq("bar", "baz")))`.

Comment: awesome! I thought the code would be more like C++ template. This works like a charm, the only problem is, passing single argument is not working. It says "inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method rowToCSV's type parameter bounds [T <: Product]", any idea how to fix this?

Comment: ummm ... I guess, you do need parenthesis around a single argument, 1-element tuples are weird anyway, who needs them? You can make something like `def valueToCSV[T](v: T) = rowToCSV((v))`